# VLOOKUP with multiple returns vertically

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vlookup

I am creating a form on worksheet 1. I want to enter a name in cell `B1` and for it to look up a list which is on worksheet 2, find the name and return the values from the cell next to the name all down the list returning multiple values into worksheet 1 in cell A3 and below.

[image: Sheet1]

[image: Sheet2]

Comment: Can you give example of the data and the desired output? I'm not sure what output you really want here.

Comment: You can type the sample data on an excel, the desired output, and screenshot and post it here. I will then help to show the image for you.

Comment: I want to enter a name on my first sheet for example Aberdeen and then a vlookup to look up my list on sheet 2 which has multiple entries for Aberdeen. Then return the asset names for Aberdeen from the list to the first sheet. It is a asset check form so if someone wants to see the sites for Aberdeen only if they enter Aberdeen at the top the list will then show below that. Or if they want assets for Inverness it will show these.

Comment: post a link to the image and I'll help showing the image for everyone

Answer (score 0):

There is a discussion of this type of problem on [this tutorial page](https://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/01/31/using-array-formula-to-look-up-multiple-values-in-a-list/).

It can't be done using VLOOKUP(), but the picture and formula below give a solution.

[image]

The search item is typed in A2, and this array formula in A3:

```
 =IFERROR(INDEX($D$2:$D$11, SMALL(IF($A$2=$C$2:$C$11, ROW($C$2:$C$11)-MIN(ROW($C$2:$C$11))+1, ""), ROW(A1))),"")
```

lists the assets associated with the search item when filled down.

Array formulas must be entered with CTRL-Shift Enter, rather than just Enter.  If entered correctly, Excel will surround the formula with curly brackets {} in the formula bar.

After entering the formula in A3, select that cell and fill down far enough to list the maximum number of assets.